# discord.js addrole command can be misused by moderators

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have created an add role command to my bot, the issue is, anyone with the mod role can misuse the bot to get higher role such as roles for the owner, can you guys share the code to add to my current one?

```
if (command === "addrole") {
  if (
    !message.member.roles.cache.some((r) =>
      ["Administrator", "Moderator"].includes(r.name)
    )
  )
    return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to add roles!");

  let member = message.mentions.members.first();
  let role = message.mentions.roles.first();
  if (!member)
    return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server");
  if (!role) return message.reply("please mention a valid role of this server");

  member.roles.add(role);
  return message.reply(
    ` ${role} has successfully been added to ${member.user.tag}`
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Role.comparePositionTo()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=comparePositionTo)

```js
const highest = member.roles.highest; // this is the members highest role

// if role is higher or equal to highest role
if(highest.comparePositionTo(role) <= 0)
  return message.channel.send('You cannot add roles equal/higher to that member\'s highest role')
```

Comment: unhandled promise rejection: roles is undefined

Comment: I think that means there's a problem with the `member` variable.

Comment: what do you suggest i do?

Comment: @peter23 I think it's because you copied the code as raw and didn't make adjustments. The `member` property is `undefined`, because it isn't `defined`. I think what you meant to do is to change `member` in this answer to `message.member`. This should fix the issue.

Comment: Actually, they defined `member` in their code as `message.mentions.members.first()`.

Comment: the code ran after i changed member to message.member, but now nobody can add roles even if they have the highest role

Comment: Ah, sorry, I accidentally wrote `>=` instead of `<=`